# Serializing / Deserializing System.Uri

Tags: serialization, ravendb

I've been using RavenDB for all of two hours, so apologies if I've missed something obvious.

I'm storing a denormalized view model with a property of type System.Uri. The Uri is serialized as a string, which is OK I guess, but throws this exception when I load the document:

```
Message=Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Uri.
Source=Newtonsoft.Json
StackTrace:
    at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\ConvertUtils.cs:line 267
    at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\ConvertUtils.cs:line 244
    at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:line 544
```

Comment: What does the Uri look like in the database?

Answer (score 7):

Got it! There are two secrets. The first is to create a JsonConverter for the Uri type.

```
public class UriJsonConverter : JsonConverter 
{

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return object.Equals(objectType, typeof (Uri));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.String:
                return CreateUri((string) reader.Value);
            case JsonToken.Null:
                return null;
            default:
                var msg = string.Format("Unable to deserialize Uri from token type {0}", reader.TokenType);
                throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
        }
    }

    private static Uri CreateUri(string uriString)
    {
        Uri uri;
        if (!Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
            if (!Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.Absolute, out uri))
                if (!Uri.TryCreate(uriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out uri))
                {
                    var msg = string.Format("Unable to determine proper UriKind for Uri {0}", uriString);
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
                }
        return uri;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (null == value)
        {
            writer.WriteNull();
            return;
        }

        var uri = value as Uri;
        if (uri != null)
        {
            writer.WriteValue(uri.OriginalString);
            return;
        }
        var msg = string.Format("Unable to serialize {0} with {1}", value.GetType(), typeof (UriJsonConverter));
        throw new InvalidOperationException(msg);
    }

}
```

The second is to register the converter with the RavenDB serializer.

```
private static DocumentStore OpenStore()
{
    var store = new DocumentStore()
                    {
                        ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB"
                    };

    store.Conventions.CustomizeJsonSerializer = CustomJsonSerializer;

    store.Initialize();
    return store;
}

private static void CustomJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    serializer.Converters.Add(new UriJsonConverter());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive what `Newtonsoft` is doing under the covers, but if it's calling `new System.Uri("/about-us")` without specifying `UriKind.Relative` in the constructor a `UriFormatException` will be thrown.

So, depending on how your Uri is being created in your model, it might be an option for you to ensure it's absolute before storing it.

I'm not positive, but I would think a Uri like `new System.Uri("http://foo.com/about-us")` would be stored as "http://foo.com/about-us" and would convert OK when it comes back out.

Comment: I'm getting a different exception entirely. Looking at the stack trace and exception, it seems that Newtonsoft is just trying to assign a string to the System.Uri property of my view model.